# LocationListener doesn't provide update after sometime in android service

Tags: java, android, locationlistener, background-service, android-gps

I am writing an application where I need to get the location updates really fast from background.
Hence, I've written a service to achieve the required outcome.

I am starting the service from an activity's onCreate() method.

The problem I am facing is, the service is able to provide location update for about 20 to 30 seconds from the time of activation of service. Then I am not getting any updates.

Here is the code for the service:

```
public class MyLocService extends Service
        implements
        LocationListener{

  private final LocationListener locationListener = this;

@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (checkPermission()) {
                    manager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

                    manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
                    manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
                }
                else{
                    //Request Permission
                    Intent permissionIntent = new Intent();
                    permissionIntent.setAction(LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUIRED);
                    sendBroadcast(permissionIntent);
                }
                Looper.loop();
            }
        };

        handler.post(runnable);

        //Create notification nad run in foreground
        startForeground(
                NotificationCreator.getNotificationId(),
                NotificationCreator.getNotification(context)
        );

        return Service.START_STICKY;

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
     Log.d("LocUpdate",  location.getLatitude() + " : " + location.getLongitude());
}
```

Every time I start the service from the activity like :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyLocService.class);
startService(intent);
```

I get updates in the onLocationChange() for 20 to 30 seconds.

Another observation is : if I keep the activity (from where I am starting the service open and visible) then I continue to get the location updates.
However when I close the activity or kill the app and allow the service (alone) to run in the background, I am not getting any location updates although the service is running as I can see the notification at the top of my screen.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you see the service running on running apps list? Does your phone allow the service to run? Some phones rom don't allow per default START_STICKY to restart service if it gets killed

Comment: Yea. I can see the service running. I am testing on redmi note 4 with marshmallow. What is the way out?

Comment: I had a problem with my redmi note 3 because MIUI doesn't let by default the services restart if they get killed. Try this, go to Settings > Permissions> Autostart > and allow your app to autostart

Comment: And maybe just a small tip. In order to improve battery perfomance and still have a nice precision, you could try to use `FusedLocationApi`. Also try inserting some minimum time between updates

Comment: The auto start is enabled for my app. I've used fused location but the result is same. The location listener stops providing location updates.

Comment: In the app i did that uses locationListener, I initialize the service location updates just doing: `LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);` without using any runnable, being that `this` is `public class LocationService extends Service implements LocationListener`. What is your `locationListener` variable?

Comment: locationListener is set to 'this'.

Comment: I'm not sure then, does it work on Activity? I based mine on this and works: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/blob/master/LocationUpdates/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/location/sample/locationupdates/MainActivity.java

Comment: Solved it!!!battery optimization was restricting background activity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've solved the problem. Turn off the battery optimization in miui or add the app as exception. Code works perfectly.